# Gather complete, historical Windows Update history in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-update

I am trying to get a list of all updates that a system has ever installed according to the *Settings* app using PowerShell, with the end goal being a 1:1 comparison between the two.
Lazy tech blogs will give you one of the following, which polls the Win32_QuickFixEngineering WMI location:

```
get-hotfix
wmic qfe list full
get-wmiobject win32_quickfixengineering
```

But this doesn't account for everything. According to Microsoft:

> Starting with Windows Vista, this class returns only the updates supplied by Microsoft Windows Installer (MSI), Windows Update, Microsoft Update, or Windows Server Update Services. It does not include updates that are supplied by Component Based Servicing (CBS), or other non-hotfix programs or apps.

To supplement this, you'll often see code blocks interfacing with the "Windows.Update.Session" COM Object in PowerShell doing something like this to achieve a (different) list of installed updates:

```
$Session = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session
$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$historyCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()
```

But even *this* doesn't grab an entire, historical list -- I would imagine because the list being pulled from is de-duplicating updates that were installed as Cumulatives and omitting updates that were installed for earlier versions of Windows.
The *Settings* app, however, lists things installed back over a year ago on my device:

[image: List of updates installed in 2020]

Is there a way, using PowerShell, to access *this* list? Where is *Settings* getting it from?

Comment: Try this [PowerShell script](https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/how_to_check_your_windows_update_history_with_powershell.html). (No point in writing an answer if it doesn't work.)

Comment: My question already includes all of the commands listed in this post.

Comment: Try NirSoft's [WinUpdatesList](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wul.html), it might do better.

Comment: I need it in PowerShell.

Comment: Try anyway - if it can show everything than we might have a direction.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [PSWindowsUpdate](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSWindowsUpdate/2.2.0.2) module. The `Get-WUHistory` cmdlet uses the same windows update api (wua) that you tried in your question, but does some additional magic in the background to make things readable:

```
$history = Get-WUHistory -Last 1000

# Larger than in Settings app, since it includes failed updates
$history.Count
62 

$history | sort date -desc | 
  Format-Table Date,KB,@{l='Category';e={[string]$_.Categories[0].Name}},Title
```

```
Date                   KB        Category                           Title               
----                   --        --------                           -----               
7/16/2021 4:19:43 PM   KB5004237 Windows 10, version 1903 and later 2021-07 Cumulativ...
7/16/2021 4:00:44 PM   KB5003537 Windows 10, version 1903 and later 2021-07 Cumulativ...
7/15/2021 5:06:18 PM   KB890830  Windows 10                         Windows Malicious...
7/7/2021 4:22:58 PM    KB5004945 Windows 10, version 1903 and later 2021-07 Cumulativ...
```

This is the best option I think, though I noticed it doesn't seem to be able to pick up the KB number for new update types like the "Feature Update via Enablement Package", and currently a bug with this module requires a `-Last (days)` flag or it will loop forever.

I can't confirm what the history limit is, but mine does go back slightly farther than one year.

Comment: The API I mention in the question doesn't return all the results, so nor does this.

Comment: @seagull Which updates does `Get-WUHistory` not return for you? I've only found that the settings menu includes fewer updates than the command finds. For example, the settings menu excludes certain "Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool" updates.

Comment: Check my screenshot in OP. Nothing from before the last six months is listed. I suspect because Settings isn't listing installed updates from the API but rather an historical source, an XML or something.

Comment: The SystemSettings.exe app uses the new Modern Update Settings api via `C:\Windows\System32\MusUpdateHandlers.dll`, and the UpdateStore files like `C:\ProgramData\USOPrivate\UpdateStore\store.db` to generate the list. They don't seem to be publicly documented anywhere that I could find - maybe the ReverseEngineering board can help? It also calls the wuapi at one point like everything else, so that may still be what you end up with.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

Does this get what you are looking for?

[GitHub Gist - Rugby-Ball](https://gist.github.com/Rugby-Ball/c1dee8d17d690120b1e7933934dbad69)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No, it doesn't. You can see the "createUpdateSearcher" code in both my OP and in your Gist; it's a reimplementation of the same flawed principle. Thanks for chipping in though.